# Docker-compose up not executing updated Dockerfile

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

I have made edits to a Dockerfile to install some PHP modules from PECL and packages via apt-get. To my disappointment, none of them seem to have worked.

I then tried to test my execution process by adding a string test to my Dockerfile, `docker-compose down`ing all my containers and then calling `docker-compose up -d` to see if the Dockerfile gets executed but my containers loaded with no complaints about the test string.

Below is my code:

```
test
RUN pecl update-channels;
RUN pecl install memcache;
RUN service memcached start
RUN apt-get install memcached -y
```

I have manually typed each one of those commands (with the exception of test, of course) and everything worked as expected. I then put the commands into my Dockerfile so I don't have to manually execute them. Which is where this issue began.

What am I missing?

Comment: Does `docker-compose up -d --build` help? You need to re-build the container.

Comment: Thanks @kate-melnykova
That's precisely what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More extended answer from above.

Roughly speaking, `docker-compose up` starts the container. In other words, it takes the existing container and runs it. `docker-compose up --build` re-builds the container. Therefore, to add new services, packages, etc., you need to re-build the container.